# rails 3 is printing html tags to screen instead of rendering them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using vhochstein's fork of active_scaffold, which runs quite nicely on rails 3, except for a few small bugs - http://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold.

In rails 2.3, the following code disables a link:

```
return "<a class='disabled'>#{text}</a>" unless authorized
```

But in Rails 3, it causes the escaped html tags to be printed out instead as in the following photo:

[image: https://internet-websites.s3.amazonaws.com/image2886.png]

How can I make the content of this return statement render the way it should in rails 3?

The code above, is from the `list_column_helpers.rb` file in vendor/plugins/active_scaffold/helpers/

UPDATE:

Floatless fixed this by suggesting to add `.html_safe` to the code.

I have since found that the folowing change also needs to be made as there's more than one bit of code that is respondible for disabling action links in active_Scaffold:

In /plugins/active_scaffold/frontends/default/views/_list_actions.html.erb change:

```
<%= record.authorized_for?(:crud_type => etc etc etc -%>

By making it use "raw"

i.e. 

<%= raw record.authorized_for?(:crud_type => etc etc etc -%>
```

Anyway, thanks to floatless and hopefully mr hochstein will be able to use this stuff.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
return "<a class='disabled'>#{text}</a>".html_safe unless authorized
```

Comment: awesome!  you fixed it.  I've emailed the gitrepo owner to let him know about the thread so he can incorporate it into his code.  thanks a lot

Comment: I forked active_scaffold and added the fixes http://github.com/murdoch/active_scaffold